# Stringize operator on argument with spaces

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-2019

I have

```
#define ARG(TEXT , REPLACEMENT) replace(#TEXT, REPLACEMENT)
```

so

```
QString str= QString("%ONE, %TWO").ARG(%ONE, "1").ARG(%TWO, "2");
```

becomes

```
str= QString("%ONE, %TWO").replace("%ONE", "1").replace("%TWO", "2");
//str = "1, 2"
```

The problem is that VS2019, when formatting the code (Edit.FormatSelection) interprets that % sign as an operator and adds a whitespace

```
QString str= QString("%ONE, %TWO").ARG(% ONE, "1").ARG(% TWO, "2");
```

(I think it's a bug in VS). The code compiles without warnings.

As I am dealing with some ancient code that has this "feature" spread, I'm worried to auto-format text containing this and break functionality.

Is there a way at compile time to detect such arguments to a macro having space(s)?

Comment: My first thought about your macro, was "why does the user have to quote the second argument but not the first"? If you resolved that by making the user write `.ARG("%ONE", "1")`, the problem would go away (and the macro would be more consistent). Not an answer to your question, but a possible alternative approach...

Comment: Seems like the formater sees an operator (`%`) followed by an identifier (`ONE`) so it is adding space. It doesn't look at much in the way of context.

Comment: Despite first appearances, it seems this question is about a feature of the VS IDE,  not anything to do with compilation or the language ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can say it's a bug in the formatter. How's it supposed to know that `%ONE` isn't part of an expression? I mostly agree that it would be cleaner to either ask the user to write `.ARG("%ONE", "1") or to add the `%` automatically so that the user writes `.ARG(ONE, "1")`). But since this is presumably legacy code, I guess what you've got is what you've got. I added a very hacky answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way at compile time to detect such arguments to a macro having space(s)?

Here's what I would do:

```
#define ARG(TEXT, REPLACEMENT) \
    replace([]{ \
        static constexpr char x[] = #TEXT; \
        static_assert(x[0] == '%' && x[1] != ' '); \
        return x; \
    }(), REPLACEMENT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently some time in the next decade C++ will provide a better solution, and indeed there might be a much less clunky solution than the one I provide below, but it's maybe a place to start.

This version uses the Boost Preprocessor library to do a repetition which would have been straight-forward to write with a template if C++ allowed string literals as template arguments, a feature which has not yet gotten into the standard for motivations I can only guess at. So it doesn't actually test whether the argument has no spaces; rather it tests that there are no spaces in the first 64 characters (where 64 is an almost entirely arbitrary number which can be changed as your needs dictate). I used the Boost Preprocessor library; you could do this with your own special purpose macros if for some reason you don't want to use Boost.

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#define NO_SPACE_AT_N(z, N, s) && (N >= sizeof(s) || s[N] != ' ')
#define NO_SPACE(s) true BOOST_PP_REPEAT(64, NO_SPACE_AT_N, s) 
// Arbitrary constant, change as needed---^

// Produce a compile time error if there's a space.
template<bool ok> struct NoSpace {
    const char* operator()(const char* s) {
        static_assert(ok, "Unexpected space");
        return s;
    }
};

#define ARG(TEXT, REPL) replace(NoSpace<NO_SPACE(#TEXT)>()(#TEXT), REPL)
```

(Test on [gcc.godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x-RyJS).)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is to produce a compilation error when the first argument of `ARG` contains a space, I managed to get this to work:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<size_t N>
constexpr int string_validate( const char (&s)[N] )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if ( s[i] == ' ' )
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

template<int N> void assert_const() { static_assert(N, "string validation failed"); }

int replace(char const *, char const *) { return 0; }   // dummy for example
#define ARG(TEXT , REPLACEMENT) replace((assert_const<string_validate(#TEXT)>(), #TEXT), REPLACEMENT)

int main()
{
    auto b = ARG(%TWO, "2");
    auto a = ARG(% ONE, "1");   // causes assertion failure
}
```

Undoubtedly there is a shorter way. Prior to C++20 you can't use a string literal in a template parameter, hence the constexpr function to produce an integer from the string literal and then we can check the integer at compile-time by using it as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely.

Visual Studio works on source code, without running the preprocessor first and without performing what would be quite a difficult computation to work out whether the preprocessor would fundamentally alter the line it's formatting.

Besides, people don't really use macros in this way any more, or shouldn't (we have cheap functions!).

So this isn't really what the formatting feature expects.

If you can modify the code, make the user write `.ARG("%ONE", "1")`, then not only does the problem go away but also the would be more consistent.

Otherwise, you'll have to stick with formatting the code by hand.